# git + partly shared files between branches/repositories. Is it possible?

Tags: git, version-control

One team in company I work for has the following problem. They develop an application, which will have different builds (e.g. different design depending on customer). so they have some code shared between builds, and some specific to build. E.g. first build has (example is meaningless about files, it is just to understand the problem; I don't know exactly which code differs)

```
/src/class1.java  
/src/class2.java  
/res/image1.png  
/res/image2.png
```

second project contains

```
/src/class1.java  
/src/class3.java  
/res/image1.png  
/res/image3.png
```

as you see, both have class1.java and image1.png. Evething else is different. The project is much more complex of course, so to contain everything in one project is not comfortable... But also to make different branches and commit the same code to all of them is not comfortable...

probably I picked wrong direction thinking about this problem, but I just took a look at git (we use svn), and it allows separated repositories. The question is: is it possible to make different branches in git, but tell it that "these files should be shared between them" and other files should be only in those branches. Then when developer commits class1.java git synchronizes it in all branches/repositorias etc. Maybe there is another solution which can be easy taken?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is it possible to make different branches in git, but tell it that "these files should be shared between them" and other files should be only in those branches.

Err... no.
When you create a branch, that actually means that any *future* commit of any file will be recorded within that new branch.
So if you do not touch to `class1.java`, its commit will still be reference by the original branch (say '`common`'), while `class2.java` will have been removed, and `class3.java` added, all in the branch '`project1`'.
Anybody creating a branch `project2` from `common` would in effect reuse `class1.java`.

> Then when developer commits class1.java git synchronizes it in all branches/repositorias etc

Err... no bis: the developer would have to cherry-pick `class1.java` and merge it to the branch '`common`', and then rebase all the other branches on top of `common` in order to see `class1.java` evolution.

The real solution would be [`git submodules`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) (see [here for more on the way submodules are updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979167/git-submodule-update/1979194#1979194)), but that involves:

- a reorganization of the code:

```
    project
      src
        class3.java
                       #   here is a full git repo
      common           # = referenced within the 'project' repo
                       #   as submodule
        src
          class1.java
```

- still a push to the 'common' Git repo whenever `class1.java` is modified, and a git submodules update in all other branches/repos that need the new 'common' evolution.

Comment: Thank you, VonC!
It looks promising, except for one thing - project reorganization, but that will be another one, and I hope with solution too :) in few words - developers of that project likes that Eclipse makes build to Android automatically... but I think we can write our own ant or maven build which will do the same, but knowing that sources are in two directories... But in general - it looks nice, just have to try it out and if any question I will post them here ;)
merci bien!!!